# How to remove event listener from childs inside parent movieclip  in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have created event listeners for a particular movieclip.Insidet this movieclip there is so many objects.When ever i click on the parent movieclip the event listener calls the function for the child object. I had tried `removeEventLIstener()`

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var info:MovieClip=new MovieClip();

info.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.35);
info.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,300);
var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.5);
mc.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,30);
this.addChild(info);
mc.x=0;
mc.y=0;
info.x=stage.stageWidth/2
info.y=stage.stageHeight/2;
info.addChild(mc);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,msclick);
function msclick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.target.removeChild(e.target.parent);}
```

i want to delete mc's parent

Comment: You will have to be clearer with the problem statement. Usually it is best to add an excerpt of the code in question.

Comment: @Akhil Your probably going to have to show more code, as your question is still somewhat unclear. The way I have understood your question is that when you click on your parent display object, the `onMouseOver()` event handler is called for all its child objects? Also on a side note, you may want to consider revising the naming convention you have chosen to use for writing your code. For example `bubble_arr` could be `bubbleArray`, and `bubble_mc` could be `bubble` or `bubbleMC` or `bubbleMovieClip`.

Comment: @Akhil Another suggestion is that it may be simpler to store your event object's target reference in a local variable like so: `var bubble:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;`. This way you can simply access your target reference like `bubble.addChild(infoGrd)` or `bubble.name`.

Comment: now i have edited the codes so that u can easily understand

Comment: @Akhil, It's still not clear what you are asking for and what the problem is. What is actually happening in your application and what would you like to happen? Having a wild stab, you might like to look at using 'mc.mouseChildren = false' or 'currentTarget' instead of 'target'. I would also suggest putting a few trace statements in your code (eg. trace(e.target); trace(e.currentTarget); trace(e.target.parent); trace(e.currentTarget.parent)) and compare it against what you expect it to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove your `mc` display object from its parent, you can do the following:

```
function onMCClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var target:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject;
    var parent:DisplayObjectContainer = target.parent;

    parent.removeChild(target);

}// end function
```

You can also remove the event listener added to the target object by doing the following:

```
function onMCClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var target:DisplayObject = e.target as DisplayObject;

    target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onMouseClick);

}// end function
```

Answer (score 0):

**FINALLY I GOT ANSWER ...THANKYOU GUYS..........**

import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

```
var info:MovieClip=new MovieClip();

info.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.35);
info.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,300);
var mc:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0.5);
mc.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,30);

this.addChild(info);
mc.x=0;
mc.y=0;
info.x=stage.stageWidth/2
info.y=stage.stageHeight/2;
mc.name="222";
info.addChild(mc);

mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,msclick);
function msclick(e:MouseEvent):void{
trace(info.getChildByName("222"));
info.getChildByName("222").x+=100;
trace(e.target.name)
    var ob:Object=getChildByName(e.target.name);
    //this.addChild(ob);
    info.removeChild(getChildByName("222"));
    }
```